# Insert Query for time Php

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

My PHP string contain this data :

```
$OpenDate = '20-Sep-18' ;
```

but when i insert it into database it give me an error :

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Sep' in 'field list'' in C:\xampp
```

tried to replace all ' - ' to ' _ ' but it has not worked also .

EDIT :

QUERY CODE :

```
$stmt = $conn->query("INSERT INTO `ticketinfo`
(`tOrderId`)
VALUES
( ".$tOrderID.") on duplicate key update `tPLU`= ".$tPLU." , `tPrice`= ".$Total1." , `tBuy`=".$OpenDate  );
```

the problem is in the $OpenDate

Comment: The right database format is `2018-09-20`.

Comment: Please paste your query code in your question. "_Insert Query for time Php_" So, do you want to insert a "time" or a "date"?

Comment: @PhilRoggenbuck If it's a `date` field

Comment: Show is your code. It's pretty hard to debug code you can't see. It's like asking a car mechanic to fix your car without letting them look at it. Also, as the answer below says, you need to store it in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` (but that's irrelevant to the actual error you're getting).

Comment: Based on the error message, you are trying to add the value without enclosing it into quotes (and using wrong date format). So, instead of `20-Sep-18`, you should use `"2018-09-20"`.

Comment: Convert this date string into MySQL acceptable format, using: `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($OpenDate))`

Comment: i have added query code , thanks you so much guys for help .

Comment: @user9991765 use single quotes (') around your parameters, and use `mysqli_real_escape_string` also

Answer (score 1):

- [MySQL datetime format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) is `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'`. For date alone, it will be: `'YYYY-MM-DD'`
- In PHP (Application code), you will need to convert your date string to an acceptable format for MySQL. You can use [`strotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to convert your date string to a Timestamp. Then, use [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to convert into `YYYY-MM-DD`.
- Eventually, use this converted date string in your Insert query.
- Also, based on your error message, your query parameters need escaping. Please learn and implement [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Try ([**Rextester Demo**](http://rextester.com/NHT98405)):

```
$OpenDate = '20-Sep-18';
$mySQLFormatOpenDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($OpenDate));

echo $mySQLFormatOpenDate; // test display the formatted date

/* Now use $mySQLFormatOpenDate in your SQL Insert query */
```

**Additional Details for format options used:**

- `Y`   A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits   Examples: 1999 or 2003
- `m`   Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros   01 through 12
- `d`   Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros   01 to 31

Answer (score 0):

According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html the proper date format is YYYY-MM-DD, so no months in letters but in numbers. Should be 2018-09-20.